# Android seekbar textView

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have 3 seekbar to change the background color. Each seekbar har a textView from 0-255 to show the colorcode in RGB. When I slide one of the seekbar, the RGB textView change on all. How can I specify, so only the textView that belong to the seekbar, that I slide will change?

```
  private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener
        = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

    TextView seekBar1Progress;
    TextView seekBar2Progress;
    TextView seekBar3Progress;


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                  boolean fromUser) {

        updateBackground();
        seekBar1Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider1);
        seekBar1Progress.setText(" " + progress);
        seekBar2Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider2);
        seekBar2Progress.setText(" " + progress);
        seekBar3Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider3);
        seekBar3Progress.setText(" " + progress);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
};
```

Comment: your three text view response to  one seekBar listener, so it changes together

Comment: Perfect, it works now, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting SeekBar object in OnProgressChanged method, you can compare its id to your individual SeekBar. Try below code:

```
@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            if(seekBar.getId()==R.id.seekBar1){
                seekBar1Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider1);
                seekBar1Progress.setText(" " + progress);
            }else if(seekBar.getId()==R.id.seekBar2){
                seekBar2Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider2);
                seekBar2Progress.setText(" " + progress);
            }else{
                seekBar3Progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewSlider3);
                seekBar3Progress.setText(" " + progress);
            }


        }
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: Thanks, it works :-)  I used: else if (seekBar.getId()==R.id.seekBar3) instead of else.